# Get string between tags when multiple tags present

Tags: javascript, regex

Just trying to figure this one out as regex is nowhere near my strong point :(
Basically I'm trying to get the value between bbcode tags: That could look like either of the following:

```
[center]text[/center]
[left][center]text[/center][/left]
[right][left][center]text[/center][/left][/right]
```

And currently have this hideous `if else` block of code to prevent it getting large like the **third** option above.

```
   if (/\[left\]|\[\/left\]/.test(text[2])) {

        // set the value in the [left][/left] tags
        text[2] = text[2].match(/\[left\](.*?)\[\/left\]/)[1];
    } else if (/\[right\]|\[\/right\]/.test(text[2])) {

        // set value in the [right][/right] tags
        text[2] = text[2].match(/\[right\](.*?)\[\/right\]/)[1];
    } else if (/\[center\]|\[\/center\]/.test(text[2])) {

        // set value in the [right][/right] tags
        text[2] = text[2].match(/\[center\](.*?)\[\/center\]/)[1];
    }
```

What I'd like to do is shorten it down to a single regex expression to grab that value `text` from the above examples, I've gotten down to an expression like this:

```
/\[(?:center|left|right)\](.*?)\[\/(?:center|left|right)\]/
```

But as you can see in this [**RegExr demo**](http://regexr.com/3908n), it doesn't match what I need it to.

How can I achieve this?

#### Note

<s>It should only match `left|right|center` as the selected text could also have various other bbcode tags.</s>

If the string looks like this:

[center][left][img]/link/to/img.png[/img][/left][/center]

I want to get what is between the `left|center|right` tags which in this case would be:

`[img]/link/to/img.png[/img]`

More examples:

```
[center][url=lintosomething.com]LINK TEXT[/url][/center]
```

Should only get: `[url=lintosomething.com]LINK TEXT[/url]`

Or

```
[center]egibibskdfbgfdkfbg sd fgkgb fkgbgk fhwo3g regbiurb geir so go to [url=lintosomething.com]LINK TEXT[/url] and ibgri gbenkenbieurgnerougnerogrnreog erngo[/center]
```

Wanting:

```
egibibskdfbgfdkfbg sd fgkgb fkgbgk fhwo3g regbiurb geir so go to [url=lintosomething.com]LINK TEXT[/url] and ibgri gbenkenbieurgnerougnerogrnreog erngo
```

Comment: Are you trying to extract the text from the inner-most BBCode tag? (Only if it is enclosed within one of `left|center|right`)? Maybe you could update the question with some more examples of what should to be matched and what shouldn't.

Comment: @AmalMurali thats exactly right, will update with more examples now!

Comment: https://github.com/patorjk/Extendible-BBCode-Parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Ok, I think this fits your needs.

My regex:

```
/[^\]\[]*\[(\w+)[=\.\"\w]*\][^\]]+\[\/\1\][^\]\[]*/g
```

Explanation:

1. Match 0 or more characters that arent [ or ]
2. Match a single [
3. Match 1 or more of alpha characters, we'll use this later as a backreference
4. Match 0 or more of = . " or alpha characters
5. Match a single ]
6. Match 1 or more non [ characters
7. Match a single [
8. Match a single /
9. Match the same characters as step 3. (Our back reference)
10. Match a single ]
11. Match 0 or more characters that arent [ or ]

However I would like to state that if you're going to be parsing bbcodes you're almost certainly better off just using a bbparser.

Comment: Although, the last one doesn't seem to be getting the whole string..?

Comment: @Darren Yeah, realized this isn't 100% correct, I'm fixing it now will edit in a few minutes.

Comment: @Darren Ok, updated, I think that should fit your needs. Also updated the link.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just replace all those tags with empty string

```
var rawString; // your input string
var cleanedString = rawString.replace(~\[/?(left|right|center)\]~, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a capturing group like this:

```
(?:\[\w+\])*(\w+)(?:\[\/\w+\])*
```

Or with a capture group named "value" like this:

```
(?:\[\w+\])*(?<value>\w+)(?:\[\/\w+\])*
```

The first and last groups are non-capturing... `(?: ...)`
And the middle group is capturing `(\w+)`
And the middle group if named like this `(?<value>\w+)`

Note: For simplicity, I replaced your center|left|right values with \w+ but you could swap them back in with no impact.

I use an app called [RegExRX](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/regexrx/id498370702?mt=12). Here's a screenshot with the RegEx and captured values.
[image]

Lots of ways you could tweak it. Good luck!